# Tool to backup repository list

Tags: 11.10, backup, ppa

There is a utility called y-ppa-manager https://launchpad.net/y-ppa-manager which helps to manage your ppa repositories in ubuntu. One of its best features is to backup your repository list. Is there any command line or graphical tool to backup your repositories without installing any ppa tool?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
tar czf apt-sources.tar.gz /etc/apt/sources.list*
```

Comment: simple as it could be, thanks, and also thanks @calmpitbull for his answer

Comment: What about all the gpg keys, can they be backed up too? Or does ubuntu fetch them after re-install?

Comment: @marto, they are part of the base install.  You wouldn't be able to fetch anything without them.

Comment: why back up the official list then? Isn't this post about added 3rd party ppa's?

Comment: @marto, ahh, yes, PPAs have their own keys.  I'm not sure about how to back those up.

Comment: found this thread, seems useful for backing up gpg keys http://ubuntuforums.org/showpost.php?p=7783312&postcount=4

Answer (score 1):

There is a folder called **sources.list.d** and a file called **sources.list** both need to be backed up, found in **/etc/apt** 

 
I just navigated there using Nautilus and dragged them to my desktop.

 To restore I opened Nautilus as admin: in terminal **`GKSU Nautilus`** and drag back in to the same folder. 


Then in terminal: **`sudo apt-get update`** 

There may be a better way, but I am not big on terminal commands. 

**1**. Open Terminal

**2.** `sudo cp /etc/apt/sources.list /etc/apt/sources.list.backup`

**3.** `sudo cp /etc/apt/sources.list.d /etc/apt/sources.list.d.backup`

Comment: Good to mention the `source.list.d` directory explicitly since this is where you find your own ppa repository and the like, that is most probably the stuff you want to carry along.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

1. Open Terminal
2. `cd /etc/apt`
3. `gksudo gedit sources.list`
4. Copy and paste it to wherever you like.

or

1. Open Terminal
2. `sudo cp /etc/apt/sources.list /etc/apt/sources.list.backup`

Comment: does it also backup the repositories from sources.list.d folder?